# Using Oracle merge statement to merge specific rows from a group

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Using Oracle database 19c, I'm trying to figure out how to merge only the rows with the most recent date in table1 into table2. If a new row with a matching tab1_id is later added to table1, it should update the row with the matching tab1_id the next time the merge statement is run.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  tab1_id   NUMBER(2)
, log_date     DATE
, group_name  VARCHAR2(10)
, text2     VARCHAR2(10)
, text3     VARCHAR2(10)
, CONSTRAINT pk_tab1 PRIMARY KEY (tab1_id)
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, '10-FEB-21', 'group1', 'textrow1', 'textrow1');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, '09-JAN-21', 'group1', 'textrow2', 'textrow2');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, '09-MAR-21', 'group1', 'textrow3', 'textrow3');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4, '08-MAR-21', 'group2', 'textrow4', 'textrow4');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (5, '08-JAN-21', 'group2', 'textrow5', 'textrow5');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (6, '10-FEB-21', 'group2', 'textrow6', 'textrow6');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (7, '10-MAR-21', 'group3', 'textrow7', 'textrow7');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (8, '05-JAN-21', 'group3', 'textrow8', 'textrow8');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (9, '05-FEB-21', 'group3', 'textrow9', 'textrow9');
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  tab2_id   NUMBER(2)
, tab1_id   NUMBER(2) UNIQUE NOT NULL
, log_date     DATE
, group_name     VARCHAR2(10)
, text2     VARCHAR2(10)
, text3     VARCHAR2(10)
, CONSTRAINT pk_tab2 PRIMARY KEY (tab2_id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE  seq_table2_id  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  ORDER  NOCYCLE;
```

These rows should merge into TABLE2 because they contain the most recent date in the log_date column.
edit-(Results should be something like this, ignoring the tab2_id column generated from a sequence.)

```
 TAB2_ID    TAB1_ID LOG_DATE  GROUP_NAME TEXT2      TEXT3
 ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       1          3 09-MAR-21 group1     textrow3   textrow3
       2          4 08-MAR-21 group2     textrow4   textrow4
       3          7 10-MAR-21 group3     textrow7   textrow7
```

---

Update: based on Caius' comments, I got this to work:

```
MERGE INTO table2 t2
USING(
  WITH T1_TO_MERGE AS (
  SELECT
      row_number() OVER(
          PARTITION BY group_name
          ORDER BY log_date DESC
      ) row_num,
      tab1_id,
      log_date,
      group_name,
      text2,
      text3
  FROM
      table1
  )
  SELECT * FROM T1_TO_MERGE WHERE row_num = 1
     ) t1
      ON(t2.group_name = t1.group_name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET t2.tab1_id =  t1.tab1_id,
    t2.log_date = t1.log_date,
    t2.text2 = t1.text2,
    t2.text3 = t1.text3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(
    t2.tab2_id,
    t2.tab1_id,
    t2.log_date,
    t2.group_name,
    t2.text2,
    t2.text3)
VALUES
    (seq_table2_id.NEXTVAL,
    t1.tab1_id,
    t1.log_date,
    t1.group_name,
    t1.text2,
    t1.text3);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Tried anything so far?

Comment: You should look for `GROUP BY`

Comment: The whole process makes no sense. Why do you have `table2` as a stored table? It should be a **view**, selecting the most recent row for each `id` from `table1`. A view is just code (not data!) and its content is recalculated whenever you select from the view. Then, if performance is a problem, you can make it into a ***materialized*** view (where data is, in fact, *stored*) - but the data is calculated automatically, either on demand or automatically whenever the data changes in `table1`. "On demand" seems to replicate exactly what you are planning to do now, with `merge`.

Comment: "Most recent" is typically given by doing `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY what_col_is_the_same_each_row ORDER BY what_col_has_the_date_or_sequencenum DESC) rn` in a subquery and `WHERE rn=1` in the outer query. Your group_name is the partition and log_date the order